# I want to get absolute value for my Google Analytics metrics. Currently I'm getting all values of DAU,MAU and session time in terms of percentage

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I am getting the average engagement time in my analytics dashboard. I want the session time to be displayed in categories based on time:

1. Sessions less than 1 min
2. Sessions with 1-3 mins of engagement time.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options to accomplish that:

1. Create Segments for each Session length
   Under Segments > Behaviour "Session length" > 3
2. Aggregate your Data in Excel or Google Data Studio

Comment: I added it to Data studios. It is working great however i am unable to get the field of "session length" from analytics. Only getting average session time.